# Cannot required the javascript with dynamic routing in React router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

As the title, but when the Router matching none params route or use the hashHistory it can be work.

The url similar with http://127.0.0.1:8080/messages/32432

this script cannot required: http://127.0.0.1:8080/messages/12./static/12.2314d32a55a3f4ae.js

```js
const routes = {
  path: '/messages/:id',
  getComponents(location, callback) {
    require.ensure([], function (require) {
      callback(null, require('./Message'))
    })
  }
}

class AppRoute extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} ></Router>
    )
  }
}

render(<AppRoute />, document.getElementById('app'))
```